# Initialize a class once in the Activity and use in all its Fragments and related popups

Tags: java, android

For example, I have a class called `Abc` in which I define all my possible methods.

I simply initialize the class in one of my Activity and passing the instance to all its fragments (by bundle), popups (using constructure parameters) etc to call/use these possible methods.

I am little curious to know, is there any way through which I only initialize the `Abc` class in the Activity and able to access its instance within all fragments and related popups without passing by parameters.

**Update**

Let me explain the issue.

I have written all billing information in the Class called BillingManager. And I have initialized BillingManager in one of my MainActivity like :

```
BillingManager billingManager = new BillingManager(context, callback);
```

Here context is the current Context and the callback is simply to update the `MainActivity` when something will update (e.g Billing_Completed, User_Cancelled etc) inside `BillingManager`.

Till here this is fine. But If I want to use BillingManager instance inside the related Adapters, Fragments, Dialogs of MainActivity then I need to pass the instance of `BillingManager` from the MainActivity to its related Adapters, Fragments and Dialogs etc. like:

For Fragments:

```
Fragment appFrag = AppItemFragment.newInstance(billingManager);
```

For Dialogs and Adapters :

```
ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(Context, billingManager);

MyDialog dialog = MyDialog(Context, billingManager);
```

Then only I can able to use BillingManager in other areas and can handle the callback inside MainActivity.

Its pretty problematic to pass the billingmanager instance to all other areas by parameters. Something like currently I am passinbg the billingmanager instance like below:

> MainActivity -> SomeFragment -> SomeAdapter -> SomeDialog ->
>   SomeStaticMethod etc etc

So my question is: Is it possible to use BillingManager inside the Adapter or Dialog without passing the instance.

Hope its little bit understandable now.

Comment: You can use `Singleton` pattern to do this easy and clean.

Comment: Singletons must be avoided for such simple tasks @Merka

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches for this problem.

**Approach 1:**

Use interface to interact with your Activity and get all the desired object.

```
public interface InstanceProvider{
    public ABC getABCInstance();
}
```

Implement this in your Activity and then in your fragment

```
private InstanceProvider instanceProvider;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context){
    if (context instanceof InstanceProvider){
        instanceProvider = (InstanceProvider) context;
    }
}
```

And use this to get the instance in fragment

**Approach 2:**

Use Dependency Injection.

Google's owned and recommenced library for dependency Injection is [Dagger 2 dependency injection](https://google.github.io/dagger/) there are other libraries too which can be used for dependency injection.

Comment: thanks atif, Can you please explain about dependency injection

Comment: @Ranjit that is completely different and too big topic. You have to go through it yourself. It can easily take upto 2 weeks for beginners to understand dependency injection. for reference - https://google.github.io/dagger/

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can typecast the getActivity() to your activity and access the instance in all its fragment.
You can access methods in fragment like this:

```
YourActivity containerActivity = (YourActivity)getActivity();
containerActivity.whaterMethod();
```

If you want to access some variable, then create getter setter for that variable in YourActivity and the use it in the same way.

Comment: you can do this, but it's not exactly good practice. It is very tightly coupled

Comment: I would also discourage this approach, for the same reasons given by Tim. This might not seem like an issue now, but it might create more trouble down the development line.